# Class discovery, reflection, jars and jnlp

Tags: java, reflection, jar, java-web-start

In our system, we have a plugin mechanism allowing us to instanciate unknown classes at runtime.

Provided with a directory or a jar in the classpath, the system is capable to explore the contained classes and if the class implements a particular interface, it can be instanciated and used as plugin.

Everything is packaged as jars and works nice and well. However, when trying to bundle it as a webstart application, this mechanism seems to break.

More specifically, it seems like the discovery of classes doesn't work anymore:

```
public static Collection<String> getAllClassFiles()
{
    Collection<String> all_files = new ArrayList<String>();

    String pathSep = System.getProperty("path.separator");
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");

    for (String path : classpath.split(pathSep))
    {
        File filepath = new File(path);

        if (filepath.isDirectory()) 
        {
            all_files.addAll(dirContent(filepath));
        } 
        else if (path.endsWith(".jar")) 
        {

            JarFile jar;
            try {
                jar = new JarFile(filepath);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.warning("WARNING: " + filepath + " could not be opened!");
                continue;
            }

            for (Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries(); entries
                    .hasMoreElements();)
            {
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class"))
                    all_files.add(entry.getName());
            }
        } 
        else if (path.endsWith(".class")) {
            all_files.add(path);
        } 
        else {
            Log.warning("Warning: corrupt classpath entry: " + path);
        }

    }
    return all_files;
}
```

So ...this works when calling the system directly using the jars ...but not with webstart anymore despite all jars are signed and included.

Any idea how to keep it working with webstart?

Comment: no error ...just returning an empty list

Comment: ...apparently, it is because the classpath disapears using java webstart.
It becomes only: java.class.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/deploy.jar
And when I dump the system/deployment properties, I see nowhere a trace of "my" classpath nor any information of the original jars ...so, how would it be possible to gather a listing of available classes?

Answer (score 0):

You **might** be lucky by getting the context classloader and try to get its URL[]s - then streaming over the content.

I don't think this would be a good idea, either. Java is not built around reflecting content this way. But what is provided is, maybe less elegant, the possibility of reading meta data files, for example with`Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/plugins.txt")` where you can define the to be instantiated classes.

Or, even more streamlined, use ServiceLoader.

Depending on your claspath and jars, this is faster anyway than eager loading each and every class around...

Comment: I like the ServiceLoader way you pointed out ...however, it has two weak drawbacks: first, you must maintain a list of all your plugins implementations in a specific file. Then, you must insert a special mechanism so that this also works at development time, not only in jars. I agree both can be circumvented ...but it makes the final solution ...well, not so nice.

Comment: It's correct, you must maintain two sources of information, the interface or annotation with the class and the "meta" file. But it may truly be expensive to enumerate every file on the classpath. I have no difficulties doing this at development time for example in eclipse. You simply add the "META-INF/services" folder to the src folder and any declared service is in the classpath - just as in runtime. It gets exported with the jar und you dont have to care any more.

Comment: Although this may seem a satisfying approach, it has more problems then I initially recognized. First, it creates an instance of each service when getting the list. There is no way to get the list of classes with the ServiceLoader, you get the instances directly. This can be time-consuming and error-prone. Secondly, you cannot get several instances of a service (without reloading all others)

Comment: You must see this with on level of indirection: Just as in your plain reflection example you "create" a class (many, to be exact), you should create a "factory" here. So provide simply objects that have a "createService" method.

Comment: yeah, i know ...but this adds one more layer of complexity ...I agree, it's not very complex, but it's still some lines of code to add for each plugin ...so we would have: a text file listing factories which will instanciate a service ...I mean ...nothing bad with that but I have the feeling we are drifting away. If I could simply get the list of files in my jar, all of this vanishes.